# django constance: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_backend'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I am upgrading site from django 1.4 to django 1.6.2, and the constance admin page goes wrong, which reports:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_backend'
```

The error occurs at:

```
/python2.7/constance/admin.py in changelist_view, line 87
```

Which is:

```
    # First load a mapping between config name and default value
    if not self.has_change_permission(request, None):
        raise PermissionDenied
    default_initial = ((name, default)
        for name, (default, help_text) in settings.CONFIG.items())
    # Then update the mapping with actually values from the backend
    initial = dict(default_initial,
87->      **dict(config._backend.mget(settings.CONFIG.keys())))
    form = ConstanceForm(initial=initial)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConstanceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # In django 1.5 this can be replaced with self.message_user
```

I have upgraded constance, but doesn't work. Does anyone know the reason? Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe It's this one: https://github.com/comoga/django-constance/blob/master/constance/config.py

Comment: Do you have `constance` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `CONSTANCE_CONFIG` setting set?

Comment: @alecxe yes I have 'constance',
    'constance.backends.database', in the settings, and CONSTANCE_CONFIG set as document instructed.